# Are ATI Radeon 8xxxM drivers compatible with the AMD Radeon HD 8610G laptop video card?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, amd-radeon

My niece just purchased a new HP ENVY m6-k010dx Sleekbook and wants to remove Windows 8 for Windows 7. I have found compatible drivers for everything, but the video card drivers give me pause.

From the official AMD site (support.amd.com) they have a listing for 8xxxM drivers, but none for 8xxxG.

I am unable to find any information on the video card in the laptop (Even on the [HP web site](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03774486&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4132&product=5390694&sw_lang=)), that gives me any specifications other than 8610G. Before I go through the hassle of reformatting, I want to be sure that the driver is compatible.

Unfortunately, this is one of those situations where running only Nvidia cards is causing me a headache :)

Comment: Have you tried to install them they won't install if the installer detects a incompatible device also the changeling should list all devices try the install before the trformat

Comment: No I have not, I wanted to check compatibility before I went through the hassle of reformatting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [13.10 mobility driver](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-10WINBetaDriver.aspx) does support the AMD Radeon HD 8610G. I looked into the .inf file and see it listed there:

```
"%AMD990F.1%" = ati2mtag_Trinity_Mobile, PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_990F
AMD990F.1 = "AMD Radeon HD 8610G"
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help.  I was about 90% sure it was good, but it's that 10% that always gets me...